YMapDefaultSchemeLayer в яндекс картах не определен
Пытаюсь изменить тему для яндекс карт на темную
В личном кабинете яндекса получил применяемый стиль, и вставил его при инициализации своей карты.
Подключение api:
script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=Ключ&lang=ru_RU" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>

Далее создаю карту:
if($('#mapItem').length > 0) {
            ymaps.ready(initMap);
            function initMap() {
                // Получение всех элементов с классом representation-city-item
                var cityItems = document.getElementsByClassName('representation-object-item');
                var coordinatesz = cityItems[0].getAttribute('data-cord').split(',').map(Number);
                var myMap = new ymaps.Map("mapItem", {
                    center: coordinatesz,
                    zoom: 15,
                    
                });
               myMap.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({
                    theme: "dark", customization:[]
                }));
                // Перебор элементов и добавление меток на карту
                for (var i = 0; i < cityItems.length; i++) {
                    var coordinates = cityItems[i].getAttribute('data-cord').split(',').map(Number);
                    var cityName = cityItems[i].innerText;
                    var item = $(this);
                    // Создание метки
                    var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates, { 
                        hintContent: cityName,
                    
                    }, {
                        iconLayout: 'default#image', // Использование пользовательской иконки для метки
                        iconImageHref: '/images/mapIcon.svg', // Путь к исходной иконке
                        iconImageSize: [50, 50],
                        iconImageOffset: [-15, -15]
                    });
            
                    
            
                    // Добавление метки на карту
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
                   
                }
            }
        }

Получаю ошибку:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Y Map Default Scheme Layer is not defined

При том что в документации написано, что YMapDefaultSchemeLayer определен. Подскажи, что делаю не так? Может версия API не та?
